# numeric character data getting 0 when going with wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, number-formatting, wcf-data-services

The data goes right when using it with Soap. but when I use wcf my numeric data goes to 0.  It adds the letter m to the end of the number I sent as float.
When I double it, it sends it as 0 again.how can i fix this problem?

Comment: we can't see anything about your setup; possibly you haven't marked one of the data-members on the data-contract? but: we need *code* (to put it mildly: WCF and other RPC stacks generally know how to send numbers). What does "It adds the letter m to the end of the number I sent as float" even *mean*?

Comment: Can you provide your service contract implementation code?